# How to modify the uneven space between separate loop cuts, while they are already cut?

Tags: edges, loop

While I noticed how to entirely remove edge loops (by dissolving) and simply creating them anew.
I'd like to know if there's a way to modify the amount of **space** between each and **between specific** of the CTRL+R cuts **without cutting anew**?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shipped add-on Loop Tools > Space will space a selection of vertices evenly over the selected range on a single loop. To space the parallel loops in the same move, make the selection on **one** loop, as shown, and check '*Parallell (all)*'. If the points lie on a curve, the tool can make a cubic interpolation to approximate the new positions of the moved points, if you choose.

[image]

An **edge loop** is an end-to-end chain of edges on one side of one, or between two, chains of *quad* faces. It's what you get when you <kbd>Alt</kbd> right-click a single edge in Blender. <kbd>Alt</kbd> right-clicking is a good way to test that your mesh is well-formed. If the selection doesn't run where you expect it to, it indicates there is something wrong where the selection stops or diverts; a double vertex, or internal face. (An **edge ring** is a set of parallel edges along a chain of quad faces - it's what you get when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> right-click a single edge).

In your particular case, you would make a selection of vertices like the ones circled in yellow, *all on a single loop*. You can probably make that selection more reliably in vertex mode. With '*Selection*' set, those vertices would be spaced evenly along their edge. With '*Parallel*' set, the vertices on parallel loops (the visible ones circled in red) would also be spaced evenly in their respective ranges.

If you *select* vertices on another loop, such as the ones marked in red, the tool will fail - it won't know along *which* loop you want the vertices to be spaced. Horizontal, or vertical?

[image]

Comment: - I found how to disable it but I can't find the correct button or window with those tools. How do I use that addon? - What does "cubic interpolation" mean? - and what if I want to chose the width of the space make it thinner or bigger?

Comment: 2.76, but I found the addon, it wasn't enabled so that was the problem. However.... it doesn't work, or I'm doing it wrong? space twists it unbearably, and parallel all makes it the tower of Pisa https://i.postimg.cc/J4TZXZjW/sga.png

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/W113MyT9/sfa.png Still not working :( although I didn't do that "T tool" 3d view thing? Where is it and what do you mean?  Unless you mean to chose parallel on the left sidebar, which is what I did from the start anyway. Also I have a reason why I use 76, don't ask why, It'll spark irrelevant discussion that I hate to have :/ but tnx

Comment: @Pf22 Carefully study this hint again *select verts on **one** loop*. Look at Robins screenshot to check, which vertices to select during the operation.

Comment: @RobinBetts The first image is selection, but the one next to it is how it looks with parallel. I'm sorry guys, girls, I don't understand what to do. I wish I did. What constitutes as one loop? I tried the **top and just one side** this time but it still twists them like the tower of pisa, and when I just select one edge it gives me an error (because it isn't a loop I imagine). https://i.postimg.cc/sfpfhzdP/hwa.png

Comment: here's another picture of an error https://i.postimg.cc/PJ8SPyFK/gaw.png

Comment: I removed doubles-14 vertices, also everytime I try an option I load up a save. Still, what you edited is what I'm doing the whole time, by selecting those vertices the whole "part" of the object (sticking out of the roof) gets selected and in turn it looks like this: https://i.postimg.cc/kGgyktZN/hde.png wish I could just record a video to show you. I clicked each dot and the dots on the bottom (btw the cuts extend under it, it's just visible in wireframe or transparent mode. Either way,whether I select all those dots you showed or select even ones at the very bottom It still does the same :(

Comment: If you have teamviewer I would let you into my pc so we see what's happening? if you're up for that

Comment: I've had to be afk ...@Pf22   Easier and safer to share your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com .. PS.. it might be a good idea to delete some earlier comments, just to tidy up.

Comment: @RobinBetts I want to leave every comment, I speak in the name of all newbies when I say that it's nice 2 see the trial and error. But Thank you, really thank you for the help because now I somehow managed! :D I ran through various of combinations, but what I might've done is not tested one. Maybe I did but I didn't remove doubles in that situation, yet did remove doubles in other situations. Here is my process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DydXH9vxufo 4:50, I am curious about 1 thing. Why does an error pop up on 8:00 and not on 7:50 when I did the same thing just on the opposite side?

Comment: @Pf22 .. Glad you got it working. I hope to get clarification for future readers into edited answers, and out of the commentary.  I've expanded the answer with a description of edge loops. Note at 7:46 in your video, you can see 2 vertices on the near side of the tower connected to 1 (or 2 coincident) ) vertices on the far side. This is not a well-formed loop, and needs repair. I suspect it's the reason for the asymmetrical failure of the tool.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks :) Wait, how does that happen? Those can't be doubles as I didn't really do much there. So why when I grab the vertices does an extra dot exist? Also that's not the reason, I checked if the same exists on the opposite side when I use G and the same thing happens, yet the error only pops up if I use loop tools on the other side, so what's up lol.  As for the edited answer, "chains of quad faces", so you mean two vertices forming a line on a face? or on the 3d surface of an object? doesn't it work with triangles too? or uneven circles as well?

Comment: Quad just means 4 sided, so strips of them in the topology have an unambiguous  'along' direction, and 'across' direction. Just play with it for a while on a subdivided plane, alt-selecting, ctrl-alt selecting, face mode, edge mode, vertex mode.. merging a couple of verts to see where the selection goes/stops. It's pretty important, in poly modeling (in any application) to understand loops and rings well. @Pf22

Comment: Yeah but I don't even get how the extra dot is there in the first place hah